# Still purchase success but Public key signature doesn't match in in-app purchase

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using SDK In-app billing version 3. When I change YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE and run app, I still can purchase success from Google Play Store but on SDK In-app billing version 3, return error 102 (means "Public key signature doesn't match!"). Can you help about this issue?
Link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)

Comment: Which Key do you add?

Comment: I have made tutorial from SDK In-app billing version 3